# Connect Gravity Form to Analytics

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Form on Wordpress platform.
The form splited to 5 phases - its look like all of them have te same url...

I want to add Analitucs script to follow the clients, but want different code for each phase...

How can I follow my clients for each phase seperetly?

[link for the form...](https://www.visa-usa.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA/)

**Analytics code:**

```
<script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/personal_step1']);
</script>

<script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/tour_step2']);
</script>

<script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/employment_step3']);
</script>

<script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/interview_step4']);
</script>

<script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/payment_step5']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the gform_page_loaded JavaScript hook, the following page of the documentation includes an example showing how you can add GA tracking: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_page_loaded

Comment: just providing a link is not a real answer. A link can be told as a comment unless you show a detailed way for a solution.